# Rails; save a rendered views html content to file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a view with a download link to download the html source?

Answer (score 16):

@Peter 's solution worked for me.  Here is a code sample:

View:
`<%= link_to 'download this page', object_path(@object, :download => true) %>`

Controller:

```
def show
  # ...
  if params[:download]
    send_data(render_to_string, :filename => "object.html", :type => "text/html")
  else
    # render normally
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `render_to_string` instead of render, which will give you the page, then to download it use `send_data`.

[More on render to string here](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000465), and [more on `send_data` here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html).

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that in other searches, but have trouble using it. Do you have any examples?