# Rails 3 response headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Wow, what a great site! I hope this question meets the requirements :-)

Generally, this question is about how to set response headers in Rails when using the `render` method. Specifically, I have a markdown version of a document, which I would like the browser to save as a file by default, rather than display. I have found that you can set headers with the `head` method, like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html {...
  format.text { head(:content_disposition => "attachment") }
end
```

But the options for `render` don't work like this and I can't find anything to access the headers beforehand from the controller. Could anybody offer advice?

Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: I was surprised how difficult it was to find information on this: `response.headers[key] = value` is the trick.

Answer (score 2):

yes use #headers method

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html {...
  format.text do
    headers[:content_disposition] = "attachment; filename=\"filename.ext\""
    render...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure what the answer was, but this quick search of other articles came up with this: [Rails; save a rendered views html content to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941038/rails-save-a-rendered-views-html-content-to-file)

Does that do the trick?

Comment: Hey Jo! Yeah send_data is a good way I wasn't aware of, another one is to specify the header with the response object:

```response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=foo.md'```

Comment: Ah in the source for response it says to use `ActionController::Base#headers` instead. I think it's defined here, but I can't profess to understand completely what's going on:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal.rb