# Rails download http response/displayed site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, download, httpresponse, sendfile

Instead of displaying the xml file rendered by the index.api.rsb file in my browser, i want to download it. To me this sounds very simple, but I cant find a solution.

I tried the following in the controller-method:

```
def split
   if params[:export] == "yes"
       send_file *here comes the path to xml view*, :filename => "filename", :type => :xml
   end
   respond_to ...
end
```

The result is a MissingFile exception...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `:disposition` for [send_file](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_file) defaults to 'attachment', so that shouldn't be a problem.

If you have a MissingFile exception, that means the path is incorrect. `send_file` expects the path to an actual file, not a view that needs to be rendered.

For your case, [render_to_string](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Rendering.html#method-i-render_to_string) might be what you need. Refer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941038/rails-save-a-rendered-views-html-content-to-file). It renders the view and returns a string instead of setting the response body.

```
def split
  if params[:export] == "yes"
    send_data(render_to_string path_to_view, filename: "object.xml", type: :xml)
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok, but is there an option to download the rendered view?

Answer (score 0):

To force it to download it, add `:disposition => attachment` to your send_file method.

Source: [Force a link to download an MP3 rather than play it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988818/force-a-link-to-download-an-mp3-rather-than-play-it)

Comment: Still having a MissingFile exception :(

Comment: Then your path to the file is probably incorrect then as Jim said.